# jqGrid Edit Cell and afterSubmitCell

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I use jqGrid 4.9.3-pre - free jqGrid by Oleg. I want to add a new record and edit without a modal window.

I do so:

1. On loadComplete I add a new empty record with id=0.Here we can add a
   new record.
2. After adding a new entry from the database get its ID. Replace 0 value on ID.
3. After adding a new record is created another empty row, and so on.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzp91wnf/1/)

[image]

I think the problem is that the cell is still active? 
[image]

**I Found Solution.** Thank Oleg!

```
var flag = false;
....
    afterSaveCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
           $('#' + lastRowId).attr("id", respText);
        },
        afterSubmitCell: function(serverresponse, rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol){
                      var rows = $("#contract_subgrid")[0].rows;
                      lastRowId = rows[rows.length-1].id;
             var response = (serverresponse.statusText).trim();
                  if (response == 'OK'){
                      respText = serverresponse.responseText;
                    if(respText=='0' || respText==""){
                        return [true,""];
                    }
                    else {
                     $(this).jqGrid('setCell', lastRowId, 'id', respText);
                   $(this).jqGrid('addRowData', undefined, {});
                    return [true,""];
                    }
                  }else{
                    return [false,respText];
                  }
          },
        loadComplete: function () {
          if(flag === false) { 
            $(this).jqGrid('addRowData', undefined, {});
          flag = true;
          }
        },
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the scenario which you want to implement. The usage of cell editing (`cellEdit: true`) seems to me not the best choice here. In any way the `afterSubmitCell` will be never called if you use `cellsubmit:'clientArray'` which is default. The usage of `addRowData` with **the same** id="0" is not good. You can have id duplicates. You can use `$(this).jqGrid('addRowData', undefined, {});` instead. More better would be to use `$(this).jqGrid('addRow', {position: "last"})` and `inlineNav`. You need to fix `defaultValue: "Intim"` to `defaultValue: "IN"` additionally

Comment: You can use `aftersavefunc` inside of `inlineEditing` to update the rowid after saving to the server. You need to specify `editurl` for it. Look at https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/tzp91wnf/2/ where you need to add `editurl` and `aftersavefunc` of cause.

Comment: Добрый день Олег. Если не против я вам лучше напишу по русскому. Я хочу добавлять новые записи без modal window. Для этого я специально добавляю пустую строку с id=0. По идее совпадений id быть не должно. Т.к. когда мы изменяем что-то в ячейке - то это вносится в базу данных. И от сервера mysql приходит ID где была добавлена запись. Далее заменяем id=0 на то, что пришло с сервера что бы избежать повтора id.

Comment: $(this).jqGrid('setCell', 0, 'id', serverresponse.responseText);
               $("#0").attr("id", serverresponse.responseText);
               $(this).jqGrid('addRowData', 0, {});

Comment: serverresponse.responseText вот здесь и будет id от сервера. Я проверил вроде работает и id меняется. Но записи  которые мы добавляем постоянно активные - в этом и проблема.

Comment: It's possible too, by I see no sense to overwrite default behavior which generate **unique** rowid for the new row. I don't underatsand what you mean with "active" rows?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ увидел ваше сообщение - попробую с inlineEditing

Comment: By the way, I have no Russian keyboard and typing on virtual keyboard very slow. If you prefer to have all communication in Russian you should post the question on http://ru.stackoverflow.com/, I have registered me on the site since a short time. You should just post me the comment with the reference to your new question to be sure that I don't skip it.

Comment: Try to solve here. I'll write in English. If you fail there will create a new topic.

Comment: "active" rows I added an example in topic. When we turn to the other cell which was edited record remains active as in the picture above

Comment: I still don't understand what you name "active". Is the row still in inline editing mode? What scenario you mean? What you did before? What is your current code (do you use inline editing only)? Do you save the data by pressing Enter key, or by clicking of "Save" button of the `inlineNav` or by usage your custom "Save" button? What do the custom "Save" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't understand the scenario which you want to implement. The usage of cell editing (`cellEdit: true`) seems to me not the best choice here. In any way the `afterSubmitCell` will be never called if you use `cellsubmit:'clientArray'`, which is default. The usage of `addRowData` with the same `id="0"` is not good. You can produce id duplicates. You can use

```
$(this).jqGrid('addRowData', undefined, {});
```

instead. The usage of `undefined` as the rowid will generate new *unique* rowid. More better would be to use

```
$(this).jqGrid('addRow', {position: "last"});
```

and `inlineNav`. You need to fix `defaultValue: "Intim"` to `defaultValue: "IN"` additionally.

You can define `aftersavefunc` inside of `inlineEditing` to update the rowid after saving to the server. You need to specify `editurl` for it. Look at jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/tzp91wnf/2 where you need to add `editurl` and `aftersavefunc` of cause. You need to use both `.attr("id", newId)` and `.jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'id', newId)` to update the id after it will be generated by the backend.